# Silverlight 4 DataForm Description Indicator - Can I use it without the DataForm

Tags: silverlight-4.0, dataform

The Silverlight 4 DataForm control has a handy information icon that appears next to a field to display the Description stored in metadata.

Assuming I have a screen where I am not using the DataForm, is that information icon a resource that can be picked up from somewhere (Control, UserControl, Template, Image etc) - i.e. is it possible for me to duplicate that effect without the DataForm?  I would want to supply the description information directly rather than using metadata too.

Answer (score 1):

Its a Control that is available, but hidden by default.  It the DescriptionViewer control, that is also part of the Silverlight toolkit.